Как мне реализовать пересылку сообщений из бота в отдельный чат?
Допустим юзер нажимает на кнопку, условно, "обратиться в поддержку", когда он ее нажал, появляется текст и юзер может задать свой вопрос. Как мне сделать так, чтобы сообщение из бота пересылалось в отдельный чат?
Бота пишу на aiogram 3.x
